# Mock a generic method with Constraint using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, generics, moq

I am trying to Mock a **generic method** in a class. I am new to [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and am not able to figure out the right way of mocking the method.

My code which needs to be tested and mocked.

```
public class WebServicesManager
{
    public static void Function1<TClient>()
        where TClient : SoapHttpClientProtocol, new()
    {
       //code
    }
}
```

The generic method `Function1` accepts the generic type, which inherits from [`SoapHttpClientProtocol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is basically the proxy for legacy asmx web services.

For testing the above method, am trying to mock the generic type parameter `TClient`. But I need the right method to do this, I tried the following code, but I am unable to find the right code.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Function1Test()
    {
        var mockService = new Mock<SoapHttpClientProtocol>();
        WebServicesManager.Function1<????>();
    }
```

One of the approaches that I thought of was to use a `FakeClass` which inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` and then to call the generic method using the Fake class.

Also, I have read other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615093/how-to-mock-a-web-service), most of them suggest to use an interface, which is correct but in my case, since the proxy code is Auto generated (client-side proxy code), so I have the limitation that I can't use the Interface.

Is it possible that I can mock the class `SoapHttpClientProtocol` and pass it as a generic parameter?

Comment: If your generic constraint requires something that can be instantiated inside of the method (`new()`), creating a mock instance isn't going to do anything for you.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your point? My understanding is that Moq should be able to call the constructor.

Comment: Moq will give you an instance of a type that implements a given interface. It does not create types, hence you can't specify it as a type argument. The only way you could do this would be through getting an object from Mock and determining it's type and then creating an instance of the `Function1`-method through reflection, but I think you need to find a better way of doing that. If you could tell us what it is you're trying to test we could provide alternative solutions to achieve what you want to do

Comment: @Kenneth, in the WebServicesManager the Function1 is code for initialization of the web services proxy which derive from class SoapHttpClientProtocol.

Comment: Is there any problem in just using `Function1<SoapHttpClientProtocol>` ? In case that's an abstract class (and thus doesn't satisfy the `new()`-constraint, I'd just create a fake class that inherits from it.

Comment: @Kenneth, using `Function1<SoapHttpClientProtocol>() ` throws error *WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy classes*. Regarding FakeClass, I already posted that in original question that as one option, I was thinking of solving this in Moq

Answer (score 1):

> One of the approaches that I thought of was to use a FakeClass which inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol and then to call the generic method using the Fake class.
>
> Is it possible that I can mock the class SoapHttpClientProtocol and pass it as a generic parameter?

Yes, if you wrap the mock in the FakeClass.

```
public class FakeClient : SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    public static Mock<SoapHttpClientProtocol> Mock { get; set; }

    public override object GetData() => Mock.Object.GetData();

    public override object SendData(object data) => Mock.Object.SendData(data);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Function1Test()
{
    FakeClient.Mock = new Mock<SoapHttpClientProtocol>();
    FakeClient.Mock.Setup(mock => mock.GetData()).Returns(...));
    FakeClient.Mock.Setup(mock => mock.SendData(It.IsAny<object>())).Callback(...));

    WebServicesManager.Function1<FakeClient>();
}
```